# How to get raw resource file name by id?

Tags: java, android

I have .ogg files in res/raw, I have implemented a feature to save file to sdcard, and I want to set file name from original file.

Comment: What's your question? You have a resource ID as a int "R.raw.music", and you're trying to get the string "music" from that?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should work with [resources.getResourceName(  );](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceByName%28int%29)

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what the OP is asking for?

Comment: Sneaky, you linked to the right function, but the answer itself has the wrong function. I guess that's how you swayed the OP :)

Comment: fortunately it was not a porn link, you would have said I did this on purpose to appeal the OP ;)

Comment: there is no method by name  resources.getResourceByName( )

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Resources.getResourceName(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) to get `package:type/entryname`, or `Resources.getResourceEntryName(id)` to get entry name (file name.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the name from a resource ID, you can use [Resources.getResourceName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29). You can get the Resources object using `Context.getResources()`.

Personally, I'd rather store an array of strings in your strings.xml and map that to the resource IDs, but it depends on what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but in case others are trying to do the same thing, this worked for getting the filename:

```
Resources myResources = context.getResources();

String myFileName = myResources.getString((int)R.raw.myFile);
```

For some reason, even though `R.raw.myFile` is of the type: "final int"
and `Resources.getString()` takes parameter "int id",

if you don't cast `R.raw.myFile` to int, Lint will flag the line with the error 
"Expected resource of type string"

Although looking through the documentation, there doesn't seem to be an overloaded version of `Resources.getString()` that takes a string parameter.

I am on Android Studio v3.6.3, supporting a minimum SDK of 21.